# Displaying a currency value

Tags: vb.net, finance

When a user clicks on "Case", it pops up a box where they have to input a number, which is later used to calculate the value to Euro and around to other values. After this, it checks which value is larger than 0 and writes it to the display box with a white line between each value.

I want to optimize this code. What's the best way to do it (meaning fewer double lines)? I am reading through the book but as far as I know, there's nothing on optimizing the code (it seems ridiculous to write those lines every time).

```
Private Sub munteenheidlistbox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles munteenheidlistbox.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' On case selection pops up the Inputbox to set a number
    ' When a number is set it checks if its inside the paramets if not pops a msgbox and repops the Inputbox for new user input
    ' On case else pops up a msgbox saying the user should click on a valuta instead.
    Select Case munteenheidlistbox.SelectedIndex
        Case 0
            usdvalue = InputBox("Geef de wisselkoers (> 0 en < 500) voor de Euro tov Amerikaanse dollars (1 Eur = .... Amerikaanse Dollars")
            Do Until usdvalue >= 0 And usdvalue <= 500
                MsgBox("De parameters vallen buiten de wisselkoers. Lees de text nog maals in het volgende scherm")
                usdvalue = InputBox("Geef de wisselkoers (> 0 en < 500) voor de Euro tov Amerikaanse dollars (1 Eur = .... Amerikaanse Dollars")
            Loop
        Case 2
            gbpvalue = InputBox("Geef de wisselkoers (> 0 en < 500) voor de Euro tov Britse Ponden (1 Eur = .... Britse Ponden")
            Do Until gbpvalue >= 0 And gbpvalue <= 500
                MsgBox("De parameters vallen buiten de wisselkoers. Lees de text nog maals in het volgende scherm")
                gbpvalue = InputBox("Geef de wisselkoers (> 0 en < 500) voor de Euro tov Amerikaanse dollars (1 Eur = .... Amerikaanse Dollars")
            Loop
        Case 4
            eurovalue = MsgBox("Wissel koers van Euro naar Euro is altijd 1.")
            eurovalue = 1
        Case 6
            rusvalue = InputBox("Geef de wisselkoers (> 0 en < 500) voor de Euro tov Russische Roebel (1 Eur = .... Russische Roebel")
            Do Until rusvalue >= 0 And rusvalue <= 500
                MsgBox("De parameters vallen buiten de wisselkoers. Lees de text nog maals in het volgende scherm")
                rusvalue = InputBox("Geef de wisselkoers (> 0 en < 500) voor de Euro tov Amerikaanse dollars (1 Eur = .... Amerikaanse Dollars")
            Loop
        Case 8
            japyenvalue = InputBox("Geef de wisselkoers (> 0 en < 500) voor de Euro tov Japanese Yen (1 Eur = .... Japanse Yen")
            Do Until japyenvalue >= 0 And japyenvalue <= 500
                MsgBox("De parameters vallen buiten de wisselkoers. Lees de text nog maals in het volgende scherm")
                japyenvalue = InputBox("Geef de wisselkoers (> 0 en < 500) voor de Euro tov Amerikaanse dollars (1 Eur = .... Amerikaanse Dollars")
            Loop
        Case Else
            MsgBox("Klik alstublieft op een valuta")
    End Select

    'Clear input and check which values are greater -> and rebuild textbox.
    Wisselkoersenlistbox.Clear()
    If usdvalue > 0 Then
        Wisselkoersenlistbox.Text = Wisselkoersenlistbox.Text & "1 euro = " & usdvalue & usdtext & vbCrLf
        Wisselkoersenlistbox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "")
    End If

    If gbpvalue > 0 Then
        Wisselkoersenlistbox.Text = Wisselkoersenlistbox.Text & "1 euro = " & gbpvalue & gbptext & vbCrLf
        Wisselkoersenlistbox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "")
    End If

    If eurovalue > 0 Then
        Wisselkoersenlistbox.Text = Wisselkoersenlistbox.Text & "1 euro = " & eurovalue & eurtext & vbCrLf
        Wisselkoersenlistbox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "")
    End If

    If rusvalue > 0 Then
        Wisselkoersenlistbox.Text = Wisselkoersenlistbox.Text & "1 euro = " & rusvalue & rustext & vbCrLf
        Wisselkoersenlistbox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "")
    End If

    If japyenvalue > 0 Then
        Wisselkoersenlistbox.Text = Wisselkoersenlistbox.Text & "1 euro = " & japyenvalue & japtext & vbCrLf
        Wisselkoersenlistbox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution:

```
Private currencies As New Dictionary(Of String, CurrencyItem)
Private Class CurrencyItem
    Public CurrencyName As String
    Public CurrencyPrompt As String
    Public Sub New(currencyName As String, currencyPrompt As String)
        Me.CurrencyName = currencyName
        Me.CurrencyPrompt = currencyPrompt
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    currencies.Add("USD", New CurrencyItem("USD", "Amerikaanse dollars"))
    currencies.Add("GBP", New CurrencyItem("GBP", "Britse Ponden"))
    currencies.Add("RBL", New CurrencyItem("RBL", "Russische Roebel"))
End Sub

Private Sub munteenheidlistbox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles munteenheidlistbox.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        If isValidSelection(munteenheidlistbox.SelectedIndex) Then
            calculateCurrency(translateCurrency(munteenheidlistbox.SelectedIndex))
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
    End Try
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' check if the selection is value
''' </summary>
''' <param name="selectedIndex"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
Private Function isValidSelection(selectedIndex As Integer) As Boolean
    Select Case selectedIndex
        Case 0, 2, 4, 6, 8
            Return True
        Case Else
            MsgBox("Klik alstublieft op een valuta")
            Return False
    End Select
End Function

''' <summary>
''' get a currency item
''' </summary>
''' <param name="listIndex"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
Private Function translateCurrency(listIndex As Integer) As CurrencyItem
    Select Case listIndex
        Case 0
            Return currencies("USD")
        Case 2
            Return currencies("GBP")
        Case Else    'handle not found
            '''
    End Select
End Function

''' <summary>
''' prompt and display
''' </summary>
''' <param name="currency"></param>
Private Sub calculateCurrency(currency As CurrencyItem)

    Dim curValue As Integer = CInt(InputBox(String.Format("Geef de wisselkoers (> 0 en < 500) voor de Euro tov {0} (1 Eur = .... {1}", currency.CurrencyPrompt, currency.CurrencyPrompt)))

    Do Until curValue >= 0 And curValue <= 500
        MsgBox("De parameters vallen buiten de wisselkoers. Lees de text nog maals in het volgende scherm")
        curValue = CInt(InputBox(String.Format("Geef de wisselkoers (> 0 en < 500) voor de Euro tov {0} (1 Eur = .... {1}", currency.CurrencyPrompt, currency.CurrencyPrompt)))
    Loop

    Wisselkoersenlistbox.Clear()
    If curValue > 0 Then
        Wisselkoersenlistbox.Text = String.Concat(Wisselkoersenlistbox.Text, "1 euro = ", curValue, Environment.NewLine)
        Wisselkoersenlistbox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "")
    End If
End Sub
```

My insightful observation is that the code can be reduced to a number of simpler methods.

The purpose of the `CurrencyItem` class is to support future changes without having to hard code a number of `if` statements. Separating the selected index validation, and the "calculation" on the currency allows the program to have distinct purposes for distinct methods.